# Regroupe results in an array

Tags: matlab, graph

I have an array `nodeNames` which have the following nodes :

```
nodeNames =
    'O 1'
    'O 2'
    'O 3'
    'O 4'
    'O 5'
    'O 6'
    'O 7'
    'O 8'
    'O 9'
    'O10'
```

I have a graph `H` that is composed of the following nodes :

```
C.Nodes.Name=
    'S4'
    'O10'
    'O 1'
    'O 5, O 3, S6, S8'
    'O 2, O 8, O 6, S1, S3'
    'O 9, S5, O 4, S7'
    'S2'
    'O 7'
```

I want to create an array `search` that regroup the results of a Depth-first search in `H` for every node in `nodeNames`. Something like :

```
for i=1:n
    search{i}=dfsearch(H,nodeNames{i});  
end
```

and I got his error :

```
Error in search (line 24)
src = validateNodeID(G, s);

Error in digraph/dfsearch (line 67)
t = search(false, G, s, varargin{:});

Error in test (line 27)
    search{i}=dfsearch(H,nodeNames{i});
```

I have used a single `dfsearch` and it works for `'O 1'` ,`'O 10'` and `'O 7'` because they exist in `H`
The problem is for the rest , I can't use the loop because some nodes for example `O 3` doesn't exist in `H` by their own they are regrouped in `C.Nodes.Name` with other nodes for exemple : `O 5` is regrouped with `O 3` in a single node in `H`  . Any suggestions on how can I  regroup the results of a Depth-first search in `H` for every node in `nodeNames` ?